# How to update (fetch) data with API

Tags: reactjs, json, fetch-api

I would like to update {note} from the GoalNote Component. I tried to fetch the data, same as with the togglecheck function, with is updating {completed} but it didn't work and I don't really know why. Maybe someone can help?

Explanation
This is basically a goals-List with a GoalItem showing up as soon as you put in a goal. I want it to be able to have a note-input field to note down some infos.

**GoalOverview.js**

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import Button from './Button'
import GoalItems from './GoalItems'
import DropDownMenu from "./DropDownMenu"
import CompletedLevelPopUp from './CompletedLevelPopUp'



const GoalsOverview = ({setNextLevelOpen}) => {


  const [editLevel, setEditLevel] = useState(true)

  const [goalItems, setGoalItems] = useState ([])

  const [openPopup, setOpenPopup] = useState (false)

  
  



  useEffect (() => {
     const  getGoalItems = async () => {

        const goalItemsFromServer = await fetchGoalItems()
        setGoalItems(goalItemsFromServer)
      }

    getGoalItems()

  }, [])



  useEffect (() => {
        
    var completedItems = []
    goalItems.forEach(g => g.completed === true | completedItems.push(g.completed))
    console.log(completedItems)

    if(completedItems.length > 0){
      
      function allCompl(element) {
        return element === true
        
      }
    completedItems.every(allCompl) ? setOpenPopup (true) :  setOpenPopup(false)
    
    }
  }, [goalItems])


  // Fetch Goals

  const fetchGoalItems = async () => {
    const res = await fetch ('http://localhost:5000/goalItems') 
    const data = await res.json()

    return data
  }


  //Fetch Goal
  const fetchGoal = async (id) => {
    const res = await fetch (`http://localhost:5000/goalItems/${id}`) 
    const data = await res.json()

    return data
  }



const addGoal = async (goal) =>{ 

  const res = await fetch (`http://localhost:5000/goalItems`, {
   method:'POST',
   headers:{
     'Content-type': 'application/json'
   },
   body: JSON.stringify(goal)
  })

  const data= await res.json ()
  setGoalItems([...goalItems, data])

}

const deleteGoal = async (id) => {
  await fetch(`http://localhost:5000/goalItems/${id}`, {
    method: 'DELETE'
  })

  setGoalItems(goalItems.filter((goal) => goal.id !== id)) 
  
}



const toggleChecked = async (id) =>{

  const goalToToggle = await fetchGoal(id) 
  const updatedGoal = {...goalToToggle, completed : !goalToToggle.completed}

  const res = await fetch (`http://localhost:5000/goalItems/${id}`, {
    method: 'PUT',
    headers: {
      'Content-type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(updatedGoal)
  }) 

  const data = await res.json()


  setGoalItems(goalItems.map((goal)=> goal.id === id

  ? {...goal, completed: data.completed} : goal
        
))}

const closeCompletedLevelPopup = () =>{
  setOpenPopup(false)
}


const saveNote = (goal, id) => {

   console.log({id})
}




  return (
    <header className='header'>
        <h1>Deine Ziele</h1>
        {editLevel && <DropDownMenu onAdd={addGoal}/> }
        <GoalItems goalItems={goalItems} onDelete={deleteGoal} onToggle={toggleChecked} editLevel={editLevel} saveNote={saveNote}/>
        {editLevel && <Button text='Level starten'onClick={()=> setEditLevel(!editLevel)} />}
        {openPopup ? <CompletedLevelPopUp onClose={closeCompletedLevelPopup } setNextLevelOpen={setNextLevelOpen}/> : ''}
    </header>
  )
}

export default GoalsOverview
```

**GoalItem.js Component**

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import {FaTimes} from 'react-icons/fa'
import {AiFillCheckCircle} from 'react-icons/ai'
import GoalNote from './GoalNote'



const GoalItems = ({goalItems, onDelete, onToggle, editLevel, saveNote }) => {

    const [noteBnActive, setNoteBnActive] = useState("")

    return (
        <>

        {goalItems.map((goal, index)=>( 
       // <GoalItemBox key={goal.id} goal={goal} onDelete={onDelete} onToggle={onToggle}/>))}
       <div key={index} className= {`goalItemBox ${goal.completed ? 'completed' : ''}`} onDoubleClick={()=>onToggle(goal.id, goal)}> 
       {goal.completed ? <AiFillCheckCircle/> : ''}
       <h3>{goal.text} {editLevel && <FaTimes style={{color: 'red'}} onClick={()=> onDelete(goal.id)}/>} </h3>
       <button onClick={() => setNoteBnActive ("Note")}>Notizen</button>
       <button onClick={() => setNoteBnActive ("Info")}>infos</button>
                    <div>
                    {noteBnActive === "Note" && <GoalNote saveNote={saveNote} handleInput={()=>saveNote(goal.id, goal)}>{goal.note}</GoalNote>}
                    {noteBnActive === "Info" && <p title="Info">Hier einige Infos zu diesem Ziel:</p>}
                    </div>     
       </div>))}
        </>
    )
}

export default GoalItems
```

**GoalNote.js Component**

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'


const GoalNote = ({saveNote}) => {

    const [note, setNote] = useState('')

    function handleInput(e){ 
        e.preventDefault()

        saveNote({note})
        
    }


    return (
        <div>
          <textarea title="Note" 
                    type ="text" 
                    value= {note}
                    onInput={(e)=> setNote(e.target.value)}
                    onChange= {handleInput}
                    placeholder='Füge hier Notizen, Ideen, Pläne ein'      
          />
        </div>
    )
}

export default GoalNote
```

**db.jason**

```
{
  "goalItems": [
    {
      "text": "Chrome",
      "id": 1,
      "completed": true,
      "note": ""
    }
  ]
}
```